# Current UTC time point in C++

Tags: c++, time, utc, c++20

I want to send a time point over a network connection to detect the ping time and for other calculations. The time has to have millisecond precision, but using:

```cpp
auto currently = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
    std::chrono::system_clock::now()
);
```

... returns (of course) the system time which is of course not UTC. Is there any way to calculate the UTC value without transforming the `time_point` to a `time_t` and then back again? I read something about `std::chrono::utc_clock`, but even with C++20 I can not find the definition in the `<chrono>` header.

#### Edit

This would be a working solution, but it is an awful solution, because it is very inefficient... There must be something better:

```cpp
auto currently = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
    std::chrono::system_clock::now()
);
time_t time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(currently);
struct tm *tm = gmtime(&time);
// Create a new time_point from struct tm that is in UTC now
```

Comment: [`::std::chrono::utc_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock) exists in principle but it looks like neither clang nor GCC have it in their standard libraries yet. This is quite common for the latest language standard. Not all features are implemented by all compilers yet.

Comment: `system_clock` returns a `std::chrono::time_point` which is _typically_ relative to the Unix epoch, but this is not guaranteed before C++20 ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock)). So it is completely agnostic of time zones, and in C++20 it would suit your purpose.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to detect ping time, this approach is probably useless! Clocks of different systems are rarely synchronized down to the millisecond. The typical approach is to measure the round-trip time: send a ping, wait for the peer to respond with a pong. When you receive the pong, compute the elapsed time and divide by two.

Comment: I do not know how to implement the ping calculation at the moment. But basically I want to send messages over TCP and each message should have a timestamp, because they should be logged with an according time point.

Comment: @Thomas: NTP nowadays gets you reasonably close.

Comment: @F_Schmidt: your comment about "logging _the_ time point"  suggests a simplification of reality. For human consumption, it's unlikely that milliseconds matter. For computers, you need to account for the fact that you're dealing with two unsynchronized processes, with non-trivial latencies between them, so time points are not absolute truth anyway.

Comment: Einstein would just _love_ this conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::chrono::utc_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/utc_clock) exists in the C++20 standard but neither clang nor GCC have implemented it in their standard libraries yet. This is quite common for the latest language standard. Not all features are implemented by all compilers yet.

However, since C++20, [`std::chrono::system_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) has a specified epoch, namely `1970-01-01 00:00.000 UTC`, which is the same as the implied epoch of [`std::time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t):

> `system_clock` measures Unix Time (i.e., time since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds).

Note that [`std::time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) doesn't have any specified epoch, it is just usually `1970-01-01 00:00.000 UTC`:

> Although not defined, this is almost always an integral value holding the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC, corresponding to POSIX time

So what you need to do is:

```cpp
std::chrono::time_point currently = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
    std::chrono::system_clock::now()
);
std::chrono::duration millis_since_utc_epoch = currently.time_since_epoch();

// use millis_since_utc_epoch.count() to get the milliseconds as an integer
```